# Issue with NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am continuing to get this error. Now I have gotten it for my SortSearchUtil. I've tried to do some debugging but can fix the issue. The error reads:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java PostOffice
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SortSearchUtil.selectionSort(SortSearchUtil.java:106)
    at PostOffice.sortLetters(PostOffice.java:73)
    at PostOffice.main(PostOffice.java:15)

 ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

line 106 of selection Sort is:

```
if (array[indexSmallest].compareTo(array[curPos]) > 0)
```

I don't know what could be wrong with my method. It's a standard method that was given to me by my instructor. I've tried to debug my program but I'm pretty stuck. Here is the method that the error is originating from, selectionSort:

```
   public static void selectionSort(Comparable[] array)
   {
      int curPos, indexSmallest, start;
      Comparable temp;
      for (start = 0; start < array.length - 1; start++)
      {
         indexSmallest = start;
         for (curPos = start + 1; curPos < array.length; curPos++)
            if (array[indexSmallest].compareTo(array[curPos]) > 0)
            {
               indexSmallest = curPos;
            }
          // end for
         temp = array[start];
         array[start] = array[indexSmallest];
         array[indexSmallest] = temp;
      } // end for       
   }
```

The sort method is at the bottom which calls SortSearchUtil.selectionSort of this Post Office Method:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PostOffice 
{

   private final int max = 1000;
   private Letter [] ltrAra = new Letter[max];
   private int count;

   public static void main(String [] args) 
   {
      PostOffice postOffice = new PostOffice();
      postOffice.readLetters("letters.in");
      postOffice.sortLetters();
      postOffice.printLetters();
   }

   public PostOffice() 
   {
      Letter [] Letters = ltrAra;
      this.count = 0;
   }

   public void readLetters(String filename) 
   {
      int count = 0;
      int iWork = 0;

      Scanner fin = new Scanner(filename);

      String toName, toStreet, toCity, toState, toZip;
      String fromName, fromStreet, fromCity, fromState, fromZip, temp;
      double weight;
      String sWork;
      fin = FileUtil.openInputFile(filename);
      if (fin != null)
      {
         while (fin.hasNext())
         {
            toName = fin.nextLine();
            toStreet = fin.nextLine();
            sWork = fin.nextLine();
            iWork = sWork.indexOf(",");
            toCity = sWork.substring(0, iWork);
            iWork = iWork + 2;
            toState = sWork.substring(iWork, iWork + 2);
            iWork = iWork + 3;
            toZip = sWork.substring(iWork);

            fromName = fin.nextLine();
            fromStreet = fin.nextLine();
            sWork = fin.nextLine();
            iWork = sWork.indexOf(",");
            fromCity = sWork.substring(0, iWork);
            iWork = iWork + 2;
            fromState = sWork.substring(iWork, iWork + 2);
            iWork = iWork + 3;
            fromZip = sWork.substring(iWork);

            sWork = fin.nextLine();
            weight = Double.parseDouble(sWork);   

            ltrAra[count] = new Letter(toName, toStreet, toCity, toState, toZip, fromName, fromStreet, fromCity, fromState, fromZip, weight);      
            count++;
            }
            fin.close();
         }
   }

   public void sortLetters() 
   {
     SortSearchUtil.selectionSort(ltrAra);
   }

   public void printLetters() 
   {
      for (Letter ltr : ltrAra)
      {
         System.out.println(ltr);
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

My file looks like this "letters.in":

```
Stu Steiner
123 Slacker Lane
Slackerville, IL 09035
Tom Capaul
999 Computer Nerd Court
Dweebsville, NC 28804-1359
0.50
Tom Capaul
999 Computer Nerd Court
Dweebsville, NC 28804-1359
Chris Peters
123 Some St.
Anytown, CA 92111-0389
1.55
```

Comment: Please indicate line# **106** in **SortSearchUtil.java** file.

Comment: your class has this line: 
   private Letter [] ltrAra = new Letter[max];

Comment: so it doesn't need this line in your constructor: Letter [] Letters = ltrAra;

Comment: is Letter a class that you made or did you get it from somewhere?

Comment: @PM77-1 I added the line in my last edit, thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @WillNewton I made the letter class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you get a NPE because:

You initialize `ltrAra` as array of 1000 items, but you read in less than 1000 items within method `readLetters()`. So at the end of this array some null references remain un-initialized (remember array-creation does itself not set the single items to any objects). Therefore following sorting-method gets some null-references => NPE.

**Suggested solution:**

You should use an `ArrayList` instead of an array because that will automatically prevent you from accessing too much items due to internal range check.

Comment: I would do that but it's for an assignment & we have to use an array. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: @user3500131 Well, you can always convert the list to an array though if needed. Internally I would use the list and convert it for feeding other proprietary interfaces which expect arrays and are out of your control.

Comment: Is there a way to do it while calling SortSearchUtil.selectionSort(ltrAra);?

Comment: @user3500131 Internally you hold `ltrAra` as `List`, and after filling it you call `SortSearchUtil.selectionSort(ltrAra.toArray(new Letter[ltrAra.size()]));`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answer that Meno has well stated, you need to understand when you get a Null pointer Exception.

your error-line : `if (array[indexSmallest].compareTo(array[curPos]) > 0)`

If we get NPE in this line, it is obvious that `array[indexSmallest]` is **`null`**

And when you invoke an action on `null`, you get NPE. Hope this helps you to debug, down the line.

- Also, One of the main reasons when we choose `ArrayList` over `Arrays` is when we do not know the length of the array.
- One more suggestion, you can create an `ArrayList` and then convert to `Arrays` if you want to stick with `Arrays`

To convert ArrayList of any class into array, Convert T to the respective class. For eg: if you want String array, convert T to 'String'

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

T [] students = list.toArray(new T[list.size()]);
```